black screen is all I get now known issue?
Lenovo T 530 Ubuntu 24.04.1. Some sort of powerbattery disruption this morning leaves me with a dark screen. There is an ask to logon to the laptop but not to the Linux system as far as I can tell. Can't get to a terminal. Help
